# React Native frame rate drops when passing props between screens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have noticeable drops in frame rate and screen stutters when i pass props between screens and the screen in question also depends on the passed props to render correctly. How do i optimize this behavior?

**Development environment**
 - React Native 53.0
 - React Navigation 1.1.2
 - React 16.2

Comment: The current state of the question is too broad to tell anything but have you checked [performance docs for react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html). Adding [mcve] might help to get a better answer for your question.

Comment: @bennygenel My apologies. I honestly have no idea how to make this discernible, any help re-framing the question would help, thanks.